# Laravel - can't install from my source control

Tags: php, git, bash, laravel

I need to automate my laravel project setup/**upgrade**  on my production machine from source control.

I wrote a bash script to clone the source from the GIT repo and run the setup.

The git code is going to the folder `/var/www/prod/mainapp/`, so the following bash code is running after the git command:

```
cd /var/www/prod/mainapp/app/
composer install # composer update will not work as well
php artisan dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
```

I am getting the following error when the code reaches to: `php artisan optimize`

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Providers\SocialUserProvider' not found in /var/www/prod/mainapp/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146`

in my app.php i have the following providers:

```
    App\Providers\FacebookGraphProvider::class,
    Torann\GeoIP\GeoIPServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\SocialUserProvider::class,
```

this is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "torann/geoip": "0.2.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "app/Facades",
             "app/Services"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `App\Providers\SocialUserProvider::class,` from service provider list then `composer install`

Comment: @RisulIslam but this is not robust, this is what I should do every time I upgrade? it does not make any sense...

Comment: Make sure you have a file named `SocialUserProvider` inside App\Providers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add to the classmap the line that will tell who should be autoloaded. `app/Providers`

```
"classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Facades",
         "app/Services",
         "app/Providers" //this is the missing part.
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this a few times.

My workaround is to run

```
composer install --no-scripts
```

You are getting that error due to the pre install scripts in your `composer.json` file and by adding that flag to the install process you skip these scripts.

Once you have everything installed you can then just use `composer install` and `composer update` as you usually would.